error after installing Ubuntu
[3550.957955] shutdown[1]: Could not detach loopback /dev/loop 2: Device or resource busy
[3550.9580011] shutdown[1]: Could not detach loopback /dev/loop 1: Device or resource busy
[3550 0.965195] shutdown[1]: Unable to finalize remaining loop devices, Ignoring.
